# Does Google Analytics track app(Android) usage even if user is not connected to internet?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have an app integrated with Google Analytics. I want to know whether it can track user even if they're offline or only on online. If it can't track offline usage, is there any way to track usage of the app like storing it in xml like, once user connected to internet it needs to be send to google analytics.
Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it does and it sends the data to google server when you are online. In fact, the google analytics data is not sent every time there is an event. It collects and sends hits in bulk at regular interval. By default it is set to every 30min.

```
  <!-- The dispatching period in seconds when Google Play services is
        unavailable. The default period is 1800 seconds or 30 minutes -->
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">1800</integer>
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Answer (score 1):

It will store some events on some extends.

It will send details to Google when your device connected.

So you can use Google Analytics for the offline event storage.

For more details Please check the link

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Google have already mentiond.